# Can TYPO3 Powermail send attachments to only one recipient?

Tags: typo3, powermail

is it possible to make the attachments sent in a form go to only to one recipient instead of all recipients? In my case I use the form to notify different people when someone submits a form. But only one person should receive the attachments asked on the form. Is this possible? If yes, where can I find an example?

If not, this would be a nice feature. Being able to set one or selected recipients would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box. 
The only solution would be to disable attachments for all and use a Signal to add an attachment for only one receiver, but this needs some PHP-knowledge.